# How to debug gunicorn [6383] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT?

Tags: django, gunicorn

In my busy Django 1.8 site, I get loads of 502 errors due to gunicorn worker timeout:

```
[2019-06-11 04:56:29 +0000] [6383] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6550)
[2019-06-11 04:56:31 +0000] [6383] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6439)
[2019-06-11 04:56:31 +0000] [6383] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7210)
[2019-06-11 04:56:33 +0000] [6383] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6429)
[2019-06-11 04:56:46 +0000] [6383] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6562)
[2019-06-11 04:59:41 +0000] [6383] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6560)
```

gunicorn.**version**  19.9.0

Here is my guniconrn.sh configuration

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="myapp"                                  
SOCKFILE=/tmp/gunicorn.sock   
USER=myuser                                       
GROUP=www-data                                   
NUM_WORKERS=48                                    
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings             
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=myapp.wsgi                     
MAX_REQ=20000
REQ_TIMEOUT=10
LOG_FILE=/var/log/gunicorn/error.log

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"


cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/myuser/.myappenv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR


exec /home/myuser/.myappenv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=error \
  --log-file $LOG_FILE \
   --max-requests=$MAX_REQ \
  --timeout=$REQ_TIMEOUT 
  --worker-class="egg:meinheld
#  --worker-class=eventlet
   --threads=2000`
```

The server has 128GB of RAM and a  24 core CPU.

The error usually happens when the load is +20

I have tweaked a lot of parameters from  `NUM_WORKERS`, `REQ_TIMEOUT`, `worker-class` and `threads`. But none seem to have much effect. So I've  ran out of ideas and appreciate your hints.

Comment: Your application might not responding the requests in time. Have you looked at your django logs?

Comment: @Stargazer which django logs?

Comment: Your application logs. You defined the request time to be 10 seconds, and that can be pretty low depending on your views.

Comment: Well, previously I had tried `REQ_TIMEOUT=120` but still got plenty of timeouts.

Comment: That is why you need to check on your views why the requests are taking so long to complete. This is hardly gunicorn's fault

Comment: I am currently facing a similar issue. I am thinking to set timeout=0. From the documentation, it seems like if a worker is inactive for a specified timeout period then it will be down. Why we are here talking about individual requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, my problem was not with gunicorn but with redis, which is used heavily to cache data.

As the cache is grown several hundred MB, and `appendfsync everysec` was active, it took more than 1sec to write to disk hence blocked gunicorn processes. 
So after commenting that out and using `appendfsync no` saving policy instead, the problem is gone.

Comment: I just found out mine was caused by LOGGING. Always worth a check.

Comment: @andyhasit Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @amro_ghoneim I honestly can't remember why I added this comment, and why in caps. You'll get a 502 if gunicorn cannot write to the log file, either because the directory doesn't exist, or the process doesn't have permissions. It may be that redis was unable to write to a log file, giving a 504 because of the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check that your app can connect to its database if applicable. For me I was running a Django REST API in the cloud and had to check the security group on the database server to allow connections but nothing was actually wrong with the Django+Gunicorn deployment.

Comment: **deepbreath** same. Instead of throwing a error/exception, they were timing out.  i was going mad.